# Why does my XHTML file get an access denied in IE

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xhtml, access-denied

Giving the following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Informations</title>

<script language="JavaScript">

function chargeDocument(URI) {
try {
 
 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET", URI,true);
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
  afficheTitres(xmlhttp.responseXML);
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.send(null);
 } catch(o) {alert(o);}
}

function afficheTitres(doc) {
      titres = doc.getElementsByTagName("title");
      elementol = document.createElement("ol");
      var longueur = titres.length;
      for ( k = 0; k &lt; longueur ; ++k) {
        elementli = document.createElement("li");
        elementli.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode(
            titres[k].firstChild.nodeValue
          )
        );
        elementol.appendChild(elementli);
      }
      body = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
      body.appendChild(elementol);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:chargeDocument('infos.xml');">By clicking there, you'll have the info</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the xhtml file with IE, it gives me the "By clicking there, you'll have the info", but when I click on the link, there's the pop up "access denied". Why's that ?

Comment: Local XHTML file, or from a web server?

Comment: Local XHTML file

Comment: That's an inconvenient feature of Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) then. The browser treats other local resources like the infos.xml file as being from a different origin, and since there's no permissions granted (or grantable, as far as I know) to access resources from a different origin, the access is denied. The best solution is to use a simple web server to serve the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Alohci. It can't be reached by local file protocal like `D:\infos.xml` in any browsers. If I host the file in a remote server or in localhost using `http://...`, it can show the info by clicking the text.

So you need to host it in web server to have the access to the resource. You can check the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! That worked. I installed a web server for chrome and opened the file with it.